# react-native-image-picker launchCamera in not working in android

Tags: android, react-native, android-camera, react-native-image-picker

I'm using `"react-native-image-picker": "^3.0.1"` in react native for capture image. but I got error while opening the camera in android 9.

I got error :

```
{"errorCode": "others", "errorMessage": "This library does not require Manifest.permission.CAMERA, if you add this permission in manifest then you have to obtain the same."}
```

here is my code

```js
ImagePicker.launchCamera(
          {
            includeBase64: false,
            mediaType: 'photo',
            quality: 0.8,
          },
          async (response) => {
            if (response.didCancel) {
              console.log('User cancelled image picker');
            } else if (response.error) {
              console.log('ImagePicker Error: ', response.error);
            } else {
              
            }
          },
        );
```

Comment: remove ``` Manifest.permission.CAMERA``` permission as noted in the error msg if it's set in manifest

Comment: I've already tried it, but still getting this issue

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Before capturing image, ask *camera permission* to user. In Android above *marshmallow* version you should ask *Run Time* permission as well which are called dangerous permission.

```
const requestCameraPermission = async () => {
  try {
    const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
      PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.CAMERA,
      {
        title: "App Camera Permission",
        message:"App needs access to your camera ",
        buttonNeutral: "Ask Me Later",
        buttonNegative: "Cancel",
        buttonPositive: "OK"
      }
    );
    if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
      console.log("Camera permission given");
    } else {
      console.log("Camera permission denied");
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.warn(err);
  }
};
```

And then if permission granted then inside `if` call

```
ImagePicker.launchCamera
```

Comment: This worked for me, first request permission with PermissionsAndroid, and after launchCamera

Answer (score 2):

```
We need to add run time permissions for the react-native-image-picker . We also need to add seperate permission request for camera and external storage as.please check out below code worked for me .

  const grantedcamera = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
        PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.CAMERA,
        {
          title: "App Camera Permission",
          message:"App needs access to your camera ",
          buttonNeutral: "Ask Me Later",
          buttonNegative: "Cancel",
          buttonPositive: "OK"
        }
      );
      const grantedstorage = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
        PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
        {
          title: "App Camera Permission",
          message:"App needs access to your camera ",
          buttonNeutral: "Ask Me Later",
          buttonNegative: "Cancel",
          buttonPositive: "OK"
        }
      );
      if (grantedcamera === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED && grantedstorage ===  PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
        console.log("Camera & storage permission given");
          
        var options = {
          mediaType: 'photo', //to allow only photo to select ...no video
          saveToPhotos:true,  //to store captured photo via camera to photos or else it will be stored in temp folders and will get deleted on temp clear
          includeBase64:false,
        };

        launchCamera (options, (res) => {
          console.log('Response = ', res);
    
          if (res.didCancel) {
            console.log('User cancelled image picker');
          } else if (res.error) {
            console.log('ImagePicker Error: ', res.error);
          } else if (res.customButton) {
            console.log('User tapped custom button: ', res.customButton);
            alert(res.customButton);
          } else {
           // let source = res;
            // var resourcePath1 = source.assets[0].uri;
            const source = { uri: res.uri };
            console.log('response', JSON.stringify(res));
    
             setImageSource(source.uri);
           
            
          }
        });


      } else {
        console.log("Camera permission denied");
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

this helps me

add option to android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml -> section **application**
-> param **android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"**

android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml

```
...
    <application
      ...
      android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
      ...>
```

Answer (score 0):

Fix the problem with this:

- Add await to function launchCamera
- Add includeBase64: false
- Add parameter saveToPhotos: true
- Add mediaType: 'photo'

{
includeBase64: false,
saveToPhotos: true,
mediaType: 'photo',
quality: 0.5,
}

```
 await launchCamera(
  {
    includeBase64: false,
    saveToPhotos:true,
    mediaType: 'photo',
    quality: 0.5,
  },
  (resp) => {
    try {
      if (resp.didCancel) {
        return;
      }

      if (!resp.assets) {
        return;
      }

      const assets = resp.assets[0];
      const uri = assets.uri;

      if (uri) {
        const filename = `/${documento.code}.jpg`;
        saveFileStorage(
          readFileImagePath + phoneStorageDir + filename,
          uri,
          documento,
        );
      } else {
        console.log('No hay una imagen valida');
      }
      console.log(uri);

    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  },
);
```