# React Native Image Picker Is causing the Build failed

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-image-picker

Hi This is my first app in react native. I am trying to Use react-native-image-picker. But it is not allowing me to build the app. I am getting the following error

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':react-native-image-picker:compileDebugAidl'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':react-native-image-picker:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve androidx.exifinterface:exifinterface:1.3.3.
     Required by:
         project :react-native-image-picker
      > Could not resolve androidx.exifinterface:exifinterface:1.3.3.
         > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/exifinterface/exifinterface/1.3.3/exifinterface-1.3.3.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/exifinterface/exifinterface/1.3.3/exifinterface-1.3.3.pom'.

......

BUILD FAILED in 37s
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
```

I am Using following version

> Android gradle plugin: 7.4.2    Gradle: 8.2.1

I tried cleaning the gradle inside android. I have completed the post installation steps. I tried every solution available on internet as well. Still the build is getting failed. could anyone please help me with this issue

Comment: chk this answer for complete process. May be you missed some code.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65356801/react-native-image-picker-launchcamera-in-not-working-in-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add mavenCentral() in settings.gradle like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CuHCD.png

This might work.

Another solution:
`implementation "com.android.support:exifinterface:27.1.0"`